# Excel - return True/False value by searching multiple keywords in one column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, find, keyword

I need help with returning results for several keywords in multiple columns in an Excel sheet, and I'm having trouble finding a similar scenario using search engines, so apologies if this has already been asked.

I need my Column `F` - to read 'Ready' or 'Not Ready' (or true or false) depending on the info in both in Column `D` (one of two different keywords) AND Column `E` (match one from just two keywords - Yes and No).

The criteria are:

- 'Matched' and 'Yes' = Ready
- 'Complete' and 'Yes' = Ready
- 'Complete' and 'No' = Not Ready
- And all other statuses in Column `D`, ('Awaiting Check', 'In Progress' and 'Not Registered') should also equal "Not Ready" in `F`

Pic for reference:
[image: Pic for reference here]

I've found a way for it to discount everything that isn't 'Matched' as 'Not Ready':

```
=IF(AND(D9="Matched",E9="Yes"),"Ready","Not Ready")
```

But I can't figure out how to get it to read 'Complete' AND 'Yes' as 'Ready' outside of this.

Any guidance on this is appreciated.

Comment: Just add another `ÌF`-clause in the "ELSE"-part of your formula.

Comment: ...or try `=IF(OR(E9<>"Yes";AND(D9<>"Matched";D9<>"Complete"));"Not ";"") & "Ready"`

Comment: ...alternatively (slightly shorter, but with the same result) - `=IF(AND(E9="Yes";OR(D9="Matched";D9="Complete"));"";"Not ") & "Ready"`

Comment: Thanks, @Dominque, but I'm not sure where to add the IF clause as am a beginner!

Comment: @JohnSUN Hmmm, thank you but neither of those works, unfortunately, and I receive an error message when inputting.

Comment: @JohnSUN's example uses a semicolon as the separator, you need to change it to a comma that your system uses for a separator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simplest way to do it would be to to add an `OR` to the first logic of your `AND`.

Like this:

```
=IF(AND(OR(D9="Matched",D9="Complete"),E9="Yes"),"Ready","Not Ready")
```

---

The other methods mentioned in the comments can work as well... but I think they're less clear.

- @Dominique advised to add a nested `IF` into the *value_if_false*. Like this: `=IF(AND(D9="Matched",E9="Yes"),"Ready",IF(AND(D9="Complete",E9="Yes"),"Ready","Not Ready"))`
- @JohnSUN advised to use a workaround by always having *Ready* and adding Not if not matching both. Like this: `=IF(OR(E9<>"Yes",AND(D9<>"Matched",D9<>"Complete")),"Not ","")&"Ready"` or `=IF(AND(E9="Yes",OR(D9="Matched",D9="Complete")),"","Not ") & "Ready"`